# Ruby Grape + Passenger + Apache

Tags: ruby, apache2, passenger, ruby-grape

I am trying to setup by API server with

```
grape
passenger
apache2
```

I installed the gem "passenger" and ran

```
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Placed the following in my "virtual host" configuration

ServerName api.website.com

```
LoadModule passenger_module /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-5.0.6/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-5.0.6
PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/lib/api
```

But when I restarted the server and tried accessing it via the browser, I just see the folder listing.

[image]

What do I need to do different ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I looked at how Sinatra was being deployed. I had to point the DocumentRoot to a folder "public" (or anything else). Although this folder had to exist in the same directory where my config.ru exists. And then all just worked.

My folder structure looks like this

```
/app
   |- apis.rb
   |- config.ru
   \- public
```

virtualhost.conf

```
  DocumentRoot ...../app/public
```

My solution seems to work. Although would love some explanation to it though :) Anyone has any insight into this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You have to point Passenger to a `public` dir because this allows it to first serve static files from that directory, and if no files were found request the app to process the request. This gives clear semantics for serving static files and performance gains.

```
request to /img.gif
public/img.gif exists => send it to user
----
request to /users.json
public/users.json doesnt exist =>
send request to app in public/..
```

So you have to point it to public dir even if you don't have anything in it

Comment: Thanks @lobanovadik , yes I figured as much. Although, I was wondering is there any documentation saying that the config.ru should be in the same folder which contains ?